# Need advice on an LED dimmer 0-10 V circuit

Tags: led-driver, dimming

I've setup a small system where I can control a 6 W LED. I change the brightness of the lamp by adjusting the signal 0-10 V.

[image: led dimmer wiring diagram]

Diagram (2) [image: 2] is the waveform while connecting with a phase-cutting dimmer by triac.

I have redrawn the block diagram of my idea. Block 1 I can control by phone. I would like to have a switch block to connect block 1 and block 2 together.

[image]

How can I convert the above AC signal to 0-10 VDC signal for dimming LED?

Comment: It would be *far* easier to just send that driver back and get one which is compatible with phase-control dimming instead.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have 1 driver dimming device 0-10V and 1 dimming device that can be controlled remotely by phone. My problem is control led driver from phone by connecting those 2 devices together.

Comment: You can buy LED drivers that understand TRIAC dimming, but since TRIAC dimming doesn't work very well I would replace the TRIAC dimmer if at all possible. 0-10 is usually more reliable, less likely to flicker.

Comment: @lupinn It's not entirely clear to me. What I think I'm hearing here is that you have a device that implements phase control (aka TRIAC) for dimming but that you want to somehow observe the phase from this unit and convert it into a 1-10 V (or 0-10 V) output. So that when a full half-cycle is observed then 10 V is output and when the entire half-cycle is not triggered then 0 V (or 1 V) is output. Is that it? Or am I mis-reading you? If so, this is going to require some creative thinking.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I just edited the post to be more clear

Comment: Building that "???" box is going to be a whole lot harder than just buying a dimmable LED driver that supports TRIAC dimming.  Is opening up "1" to get the PWM signal directly possible?  If so, that could be easily converted to a 0-10v signal.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt the Vctl input draws much current. Certainly not enough to heat up a 10V LDO with a diode + 1M + cap to the LDO. Then you can use a 10k Pot to control current easily.

Using a triac would be a huge mistake for this AC to Dc current controlled driver which like has a large capacitance front end rectifier.

10V/10k = 1mA, choose a suitable Hi inpuut V and low quiescent current LDO or 10V Zener or 5 RED LEDs, drive about 3 to 4 mA into the 10V regulator using 1 M series to cap from single diode or full bridge from Line on a polarized plug.  That would be   1 Mohm 1 or 2Watt or use a C divider for a 1/4W R.

Vac = 350Vp , Ir= 340uA, Rs = 1M Vrms around 240Vac 50Hz I assume.

This is a common solution. Do you need more details?

Answer (score 0):

Use a simple module.  Many board mount Ac-Dc converters are available for a few dollars.  That means, however, that you have a board with mains voltage.  Be careful.

These are 12VDC output. You can add a 10v zener and a current limiting resistor to get 10v.  Then a pot in parallel with the zener.  The wiper in the pot will deliver 0 to 10v.

https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/mornsun-america-llc/LS03-K3B12SS/13531026

https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/mornsun-america-llc/LS03-13B12R3/13531109

[image]

Or, a bit less exact...

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have 1 driver dimming device 0-10V and 1 dimming device that can be controlled remotely by phone. My problem is control led driver from phone by connecting those 2 devices together.

Comment: Your question clearly says something different than your comment... ("How can I convert the above AC signal to 0-10VDC signal for dimming led.").  Rewrite your question with the part numbers you actually have.

Comment: I just edited the post to be more clear

Answer (score 0):

I found my above solution too complicated. So I choose the solution of converting PWM signal to 0 - 10V analog signal by using op amp